# Is it safe to connect externally an infected internal HDD to another PC for data transfer?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, virus, malware

If I remove the infected drive from its computer, and connect it to another computer using SATA-to-USB connector to transfer images and documents, is it safe? Since Windows is not booted on the infected drive.

In other words, I want to know if connecting an infected HDD without booting to its OS, directly to another PC via SATA-to-USB connector, is safer than connecting it to a USB drive when the OS is booted and from the USB to the "clean" computer.

Answer (score 1):

> If I remove the infected drive from its computer, and connect it to
> another computer using SATA-to-USB connector to transfer images and
> documents, is it safe? Since Windows is not booted on the infected
> drive.

Not really safe, and there is definitely a risk.  Viruses can transfer without booting a system. That is how ransomware spreads.

If you must do this, recognize the risks, use your own computer (not someone else's), make sure the computer has top grade virus protection (Windows Defender is good).

Connect the drive in your carrier or external connection, heed any warnings that come up, copy off your documents as quickly as possible, and disconnect the drive

Then run a full virus scan on the computer you used.

You can isolate the computer by booting it from a bootable USB Key (Windows or Linux) USB Key and copying the files to an external USB drive. That could help to mitigate the risk.

Comment: I think you misread the OP. The intent is not to boot from the infected drive. "...connecting an infected HDD without booting to its OS..."

Comment: Typo on my part. I changed to "without booting a system"   I fixed that

Comment: there is definitely risk, especially if autorun is enabled on the second system. that said, something has to execute the malware, in order for its bits to become dangerous.

Comment: Out of paranoia I would probably have recommended disconnecting a machines original disk, booting from a Linux Live USB stick, *then* attaching the other systems disk via a USB adaptor to copy files I was reasonably sure were not or could not be infected to a third USB storage device after scanning with every virus scanner the system supports along with a random selection submitted to Virus Total. That third and final USB device being what I would allow to be plugged into the system with the main disk reconnected. That is the "paranoid git" approach though...

Comment: but what if I want to transfer only photos/documents, there should not be a risk since they cannot be executed right?

Comment: If you just wish to transfer documents you should be reasonably OK.  Just follow the steps in my post and do a full scan on the machine you copied to.

Comment: "photos/documents, there should not be a risk since they cannot be executed right?" - they are executed when you view/open them. And they can contain malware.

Answer (score 0):

Safety is relative. That said, read on for my recommended forensics process.

First of all, you should have Autoplay and AutoRun disabled system-wide on your forensics workstation. Secondly, disconnect the forensics workstation from all networks, wired and wireless. Thirdly, create a recovery virtual machine (VM) in something like Virtual Box, ensuring Autorun/Autoplay are disabled in the Virtual Machine as well. Consider installing a Linux distribution like Fedora or Ubuntu instead of Windows as the forensic workstation and VM's OS.

Lastly, attach and mount the external infected drive inside the recovery VM and only access the content from within that virtual environment.

Create a second testing VM running Windows and leave as normally configured. Use a second, known clean USB drive to sneakernet the data between the recovery VM and the testing VM. In this way you can check that the malware has not somehow infected what you're copying off. If you see infection in this testing VM, figure out how that happened, then delete your VMs and start from scratch, this time avoiding the actions which caused re-infection.

When you are done and satisfied that you have clean data backed up, wipe the infected media and delete the VMs.

This is a fairly safe way as there is defence in depth against accidental execution of malware and you can incrementally try recovery steps.

If all this doesn't fully make sense to you, I suggest you retain the services of someone who understands security forensics work.